# Change state of ValueNotifier<bool> when button is pressed in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hi Im fairly new to flutter and I want to change the state of `ValueNotifier<bool>` when button is pressed

Here is the bloc part:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class RegisterScreenBloc {
  ValueNotifier<bool> isUser = ValueNotifier(true);

  void changeRegister() {
    isUser = !isUser;  --> where the error occurs
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
A value of type 'bool' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ValueNotifier<bool>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'ValueNotifier<bool>'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
isUser.value = !isUser.value;
```

Comment: this is what I get: A negation operand must have a static type of 'bool', oh just add .value to the end of !isUser and the error is gone

Comment: updated code...check it once

Comment: @lava I have missed that small thing...thank you for your help

Comment: @Don don't forget to mark it as clarified. if it works for you.